# php usort with subarrays

Tags: php, usort

I am trying to sort array with usort,
but it doesn't work,
What am i doing wrong?

```
$tmp = array();
$tmp[] = array(
  'x' => 0.000123
);
$tmp[] = array(
  'x' => 0.000120
);
$tmp[] = array(
  'x' => 0.000333
);

usort($tmp, function ($a, $b) {
  return $b['x'] - $a['x'];
});

print_r($tmp);
```

Comment: Define "doesn't work". What do you expect it to do and what does it do?

Comment: sort array in desc order by "x" property

Comment: And what result do you get that differs from that expectation?

Comment: Array ( [0] => Array ( [x] => 0.000333 ) [1] => Array ( [x] => 0.00012 ) [2] => Array ( [x] => 0.000123 ) )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$tmp = array();
$tmp[] = array(
    'x' => 0.000123
);
$tmp[] = array(
    'x' => 0.000120
);
$tmp[] = array(
    'x' => 0.000333
);

usort($tmp, function ($a, $b) {
    $a = $a['x'];
    $b = $b['x'];
    if ($a == $b) {
        return 0;
    }
    return ($a < $b) ? -1 : 1;
});
```

Try this one